# how to compile box2d helloworld correctly

Tags: c++, ubuntu, box2d

I'm come back to c++ (I haven't got using it since some years) to learn myself box2d API.

I precise that I'm on Linux system (Ubuntu) and I have installed box2d(2.3.0) from source following [this guide](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_installer_box2d).

So, I try to compile the box2d included helloworld code but I got an error on instance of b2world.

> undefined reference to b2world

[There is the complete file](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.cpp).

I have try with a very more basic test but the result is the same :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
    b2World world(gravity);

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have no error including box2d.h and no error using b2Vec2, so I think box2d is installed correctly on my computer.

And I have verified that b2World is specified in box2d.h (it's the original one).

I have try to compile using g++ command and with the IDE Qt Creator but no one succeed.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to let the linker know you want to link with the Box2D library. Try adding -lBox2D to the end of your compile call.

Comment: oh yeah !! you not give me the full solution but you show me the way. I have copy-paste the libBox2d.so_v2.3.0 file into my project directory, add the directory to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and compile with the command "g++ main.cpp -o test -l Box2D". with all of that, no error anymore. If there must be a moral about my problem, it would be that I have to re-open my c++ lessons before to create some games... Thank you for this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I haven't got specified the path to box2D library.

So, I succeed to compile and execute my little hello world program following this steps :

1 ) Copy and paste the library into my project folder (I put it into a lib directory).
2 ) add path of the lib directory to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH :

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

3 ) compiling with g++ and specify to use the box2D library :

> g++ main.cpp -o test -l Box2D